# Problem with hidden service on raspberry Pi

Tags: tor-install, raspberry-pi

I have followed a few tutorials on setting up the Tor service. For some reason I can't get it on line.

Comment: You need to give a question, the steps you took, and the problem you’re having. Otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: I will answer soon

Comment: Got it working!
How do I add the gpg and sources and why should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be several error due to the configuration.

1) run tor in terminal. Check the output. If it says cannot bind tor, there may be another instance of tor is running. try stop the tor service by:

```
sudo service stop tor
```

2) After running tor successfully, check what configuration file is read by tor. Maybe you have edited the wrong configuration file. These two files are the common files:

```
/etc/tor/torrc

/var/lib/tor/torrc
```

You should add these two lines to the torrc:

```
HiddenServiceDir THE_DIRECTORY_FOR_PRIVATEKEY_AND_HOSTNAME
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

Which first lines indicated the directory name for your hidden service (private key and host name), the second line indicates the binding, for example, every connection to port 80 of your hidden service will be forwarded to 127.0.0.1:80.

3) Make sure that your hidden server is running, For example if you have configured a hidden web service at port 80 (127.0.0.1:80), be sure that the web server is running and is available.

Any further information will help to solve your problem.